# Ubuntu 21.04 (64-bit) fails to boot on QEMU raspi3 machine

Tags: boot, 64-bit, virtualization, raspberrypi, qemu

I'm trying to launch prebuilt Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi on QEMU and I managed to do that **successfully** with `20.04.2` by following steps below.

##### Download the image

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi -> (64-bit) `Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS`

##### Extract files from image

```
NAME="ubuntu-20.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi"

unxz ./${NAME}.img.xz
hdiutil mount ./${NAME}.img -mountpoint "/Volumes/${NAME}"
mkdir $NAME

cp -r /Volumes/${NAME}/vmlinuz ./${NAME}/
cp -r /Volumes/${NAME}/initrd.img ./${NAME}/
cp -r /Volumes/${NAME}/*dtb ./${NAME}/

hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/${NAME}"
```

##### Prepare the image

```
qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 ${NAME}.img ${NAME}.qcow
qemu-img resize -f qcow2 ${NAME}.qcow 4G
```

##### Launch machine

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -M raspi3 \
    -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=7 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" \
    -dtb ./$NAME/bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb \
    -kernel $NAME/vmlinuz \
    -drive id=card0,if=none,format=qcow2,index=0,file=./${NAME}.qcow \
    -device sd-card,drive=card0 \
    -initrd $NAME/initrd.img \
    -m 1G \
    -smp 4 \
    -serial stdio \
    -usb \
    -device usb-mouse \
    -device usb-kbd
```

As expected, this starts the boot process and I eventually get the login prompt in a few minutes:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-1028-raspi (buildd@bos02-arm64-034) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 20 11:30:45 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-1028.31-raspi 5.4.78)
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
...

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ubuntu ttyAMA0

ubuntu login:
```

However when I follow the exact same steps with `21.04`, QEMU launches, shows the familiar four raspberries, cursor blinks for a few times, then blinking stops and nothing else happens. I receive no serial output (unlike with `20.04`).

[image: QEMU window]

(Just in case it makes any difference) I'm running this on the following host configuration:

- macOS Mojave (10.14.6)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- 3.3 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- qemu `6.0.0` installed via [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/qemu)